# D3.js tree - Very long text on first node

Tags: jquery, d3.js, tree, data-visualization, nvd3.js

If the parent node of my D3 Tree is very long, the text is cut.
With this line I can adjust the x coords of tree.

```
.attr("transform", "translate(40, 0)");
```

But... Is possible change this coordinate (**40**, 0), depending of the lenght of first node?
Thank you.

My JSON is like:

```
var treeData = {"name" : "Text very long", "children" : [
{"name" : "A1" },
{"name" : "A2" },
{"name" : "A3", "children": [
{"name" : "A31", "children" :[
{"name" : "A311" },
{"name" : "A312" }
]}] }
]};
```

JSFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fekula/4wLab/

Comment: I think answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779186/d3-js-how-can-i-add-a-new-line-to-the-text-in-this-collapsible-tree  this question will help and suffice the need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```
    var transform;
    var size=treeData.name.length;
    if((size>1)&&(size<=5)){transform=10}
    if((size>5)&&(size<=10)){transform=100} //YOU HAVE TO ADD MORE STATEMENTS BASED ON YOUR NEEDS
....


    var vis = d3.select("#viz").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+transform+", 0)");
```

And adjust your `if-statement` based on your needs

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4wLab/1/)

Comment: I have a lot of **different** trees with very long or short node values, I can't set to 100 or other number. I need to find out the lenght of node.

Comment: The length of the node is set to `var size`. Then depending on this you set your `var transform` with multiple `if-statements`

Comment: If you are not changing the font size and style, you can simply use some formula like this: `var transform = treeData.name.length * 8;`. (The multiplying factor will vary depending on font style and size.) Otherwise, this is one of those seemingly innocent topics that are nothing but...add `body { font: normal 14px Verdana;}` to the demo above as is to see what I mean. (I am also assuming you were only concerned about your root node.)