# D3.js - How can I add a new line to the text in this Collapsible Tree?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a Collapsible Tree built by D3.
Here is the JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/mEyQW/57/

As you can see, when the nodes fully expended, the text were all overlapped.
I want to add the new line to replace the space (May have 1 or 2). For example: SDS 123 will become

SDS
123

I have tried several similar answers found in stack overflow, but still cannot solve my problem.
Could you please help on this? Presented by a JSFIDDLE will be appreciated!!

```
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children1 || d._children1 ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children1 || d._children1 ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.NickName ; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem so I had to do a little manual work. First, you need a function that will actually 'wrap' the text:

```
function wordwrap(text, max) {
  var regex = new RegExp(".{0,"+max+"}(?:\\s|$)","g");
  var lines = [];
  var line; 
  while ((line = regex.exec(text))!="") {lines.push(line);} 
  return lines
}
```

Then, you need to appy this function to each text element. In your code I would write it like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children1 || d._children1 ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children1 || d._children1 ? "end" : "start"; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
   .each(function (d) {
       if (d.NickName!=undefined) {
          var lines = wordwrap(d.NickName, 15)
          for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
             d3.select(this).append("tspan")
                 .attr("dy",13)
                 .attr("x",function(d) { 
                      return d.children1 || d._children1 ? -10 : 10; })
                  .text(lines[i])
           }
        }
});
```

The end result is this:

[image]

Of course you should spend some time adjusting the `x` position of each text element.

**EDIT**
A simpler way would be to have a wordwrap method as:

```
function wordwrap2(text) {
   var lines=text.split(" ")
   return lines
}
```

and apply it like the following:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children1 || d._children1 ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children1 || d._children1 ? "end" : "start"; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
   .each(function (d) {
       if (d.NickName!=undefined) {
          var lines = wordwrap2(d.NickName)
          for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
             d3.select(this).append("tspan")
                 .attr("dy",13)
                 .attr("x",function(d) { 
                      return d.children1 || d._children1 ? -10 : 10; })
                  .text(lines[i])
           }
        }
});
```

Here is a fiddle for this last approach: http://jsfiddle.net/mEyQW/59/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is just a PERFECT answer for my question!! THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time to split a line on comma and place the text pieces in a list format. The following adaptation worked.

```
 function splitoncomma(text) {
   var lines=text.split(",") //splits text on comma
   return lines
}

   label.append("div")
          .attr("class", "class_name")
          .each(function (d) {
            if (textValue(d)!==undefined) {
              var lines = splitoncomma(textValue(d))
              for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                d3.select(this)
                .append("text")
                .append("tspan")
                .style("float","left")// the float:left avoids default inline positioning
                .text(lines[i])
       }
    }
```

The style float left is required to avoid default inline placement.