# R collapsibleTree package: How can I add a new line to text in a Collapsible Tree using R?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, tree

I am building a collapsible tree in R using the package 'collapsibleTree'. 
You can find a small example of what I made so far [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKaBI.jpg).

I would like to insert a linebreak between the dollar amount and the percentage; so what I would like to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbMIh.png). I found a post about the same problem here:
[D3.js - How can I add a new line to the text in this Collapsible Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779186/d3-js-how-can-i-add-a-new-line-to-the-text-in-this-collapsible-tree). However, the solution is written in JavaScript, in which I have no programming experience at all.

I know that in R you can insert a linebreak using `\n`, but it does not seem to work. This is the code for the small example I made:

```
library(collapsibleTree)
data <- data.frame(Level1 = rep("Element 1: $10000 \n 100%",2),
                   Level2 = c("Subelement 1a: $6000 \n 60%",
                              "Subelement 1b: $4000 \n 40%"))
collapsibleTree(
  data,
  hierarchy = c("Level1", "Level2"),
  width = 800,
  height = 800,
  fontSize = 16,
  linkLength = 200,
  fill =  "#001a66" 
)
```

Do you have a solution for this problem in R?

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks a lot!